# jQuery image preload

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-preloader

I got a web application, in which there are some images.

Will show a overlay in my page at start and that will automatically fadeout on all images loades.

I need something like this

its rough code

```
var image1="image1.jpg";
var image2="image2.jpg";
var image4="image4.jpg";

image1 & image2 & image4 loaded then fadeout #preload and show content.
```

Please help me ... I tried this .. but not working ..

```
var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "../images/wall.jpg";

img1.onload = function() {
    alert("loaded");
};
```

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrENE/

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var images_loading = $('img').length;
$('img').load(function(){
  if(!--images_loading) {
    // all images loaded
  }
});
```

Please mind you  can't use `display:none` to hide images.

Using `display:none` will block image download by your browser. User `visibility:hidden` instead.

Comment: My initial idea was similar to this approach, however I was checking against the actual images on thier `complete` property upon one of the images loading. I prefer the idea of simply checking against the counter. It's nicer and less over-head.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fWD5M/). I've made it using mostly raw javascript.

If you want, you could use jQuerys `.load` to replace the `onload` function, and [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to replace `appendChild`